# Combine LVM volumes

Tags: linux, centos, lvm

I have no experience whatsoever with *LVM*. However, given the following situation:

```
Filesystem              Size  Used   Avail  Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_root      50G   2.1G   45G    5%   /
/dev/mapper/vg_home      1.8T  68M    1.7T   1%   /home
```

My goal is to have a single `/` mount on all available space. How can I achieve that?

Note: I don't need a separate `/home` mount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best would be to follow these steps. Login as `root` directly, no other user should be logged in.

- copy the content of `/home` to `/home.new`

  - mkdir `/home.new`
  - cp -a /home/* /home.new/`
- then unmount `/home`

  - `umount /home`
  - check if it really unmounted with `mount` or `df -hTa`
- move `/home.new` to `/home` or just the content of `/home.new/*` to `/home/*`

  - `rmdir /home`
  - `mv /home.new /home`
- now you can destroy `/dev/mapper/vg_home`

  - `lvremove /dev/mapper/vg_home`
- resize `/dev/mapper/vg_root` ( best would be to do this in LiveDVD environment or the boot media from [gparted](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) .

  - there are various posts out there about this task, so I won't outline that here.